# Parallelize a part of serial code in Fortran mpi

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fftw

I want to parallelize ONE Module in my originally serial Fortran program.
(the original serial program has several Modules involved)

To be more specific, since the Module is used to calculate FFT of a big matrix, I only want that Module to be executed in multiple processors with MPI.

The other Modules and the main program should be done by one processor.

I simplified my question to a main program and a Module below.
The main program:

```
program main
  use myfft
  implicit none

  call myfft_setup
  write(*,*) 'Hello World in main: ', myid, 'of ', nproc
  stop

end
```

The module:

```
module myfft
   use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
   implicit none
   include 'mpif.h'
   include 'fftw3-mpi.f03'
   integer :: ierr, myid, nproc

   contains

   subroutine myfft_setup
   call mpi_init(ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
   call fftw_mpi_init()

   write(*,*) 'Hello World in module: ', myid, 'of ', nproc

   call fftw_mpi_cleanup()
   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
  
   end subroutine
   end module
```

There are some FFTW functions that can be ignored.
To execute the MPI compiled code with four processors, I used the command:

```
mpirun -n 4 a.out
```

The result:

```
 Hello World in module:            0 of            4
 Hello World in module:            1 of            4
 Hello World in module:            2 of            4
 Hello World in module:            3 of            4
 Hello World in main:            0 of            0
 Hello World in main:            0 of            0
 Hello World in main:            0 of            0
 Hello World in main:            0 of            0
```

It shows that processor number 0 has done the `Hello World` four times by itself.
I would like the `Hello World` done by processor number 0 just once in the main program,
but the Hello World in module still be done in parallel version(four times with different proc).

How should I rewrite my code? or how should I change my command line?

The complete code:

```
module myfft
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       implicit none
       include 'mpif.h'
       include 'fftw3-mpi.f03'
       integer :: ierr, myid, nproc

contains

subroutine myfft_setup
       ! Parameter Definition
       implicit none

       integer(C_INTPTR_T), parameter :: L = 1024
       integer(C_INTPTR_T), parameter :: M = 1024

       !Variable Definition
       integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: alloc_local, local_M, local_j_offset
       integer(C_INTPTR_T) :: i, j

       complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), pointer :: fdata(:,:)
       complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX) :: fout


       type(C_PTR) :: plan, cdata

       integer :: ierr, myid, nproc

       real(C_DOUBLE) :: t1, t2, t3, t4, tplan, tmid, texec
!
! Initialize
   call mpi_init(ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr)
   call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
   call fftw_mpi_init()
!
!   get local data size and allocate (note dimension reversal)
   alloc_local = fftw_mpi_local_size_2d(M, L, &
    &                  MPI_COMM_WORLD, local_M, local_j_offset)
   cdata = fftw_alloc_complex(alloc_local)
   call c_f_pointer(cdata, fdata, [L,local_M])
!

!   create MPI plan for in-place forward DFT (note dimension reversal)
         t1 = MPI_wtime()
   plan = fftw_mpi_plan_dft_2d(M, L, fdata, fdata, &
    &         MPI_COMM_WORLD, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
         t2 = MPI_wtime()
!
! initialize data to some function my_function(i,j)
   do j = 1, local_M
     do i = 1, L
       call initial(i, (j + local_j_offset), L, M, fout)
       fdata(i, j) = fout
     end do
   end do
!
! compute transform (as many times as desired)
         t3 = MPI_wtime()
   call fftw_mpi_execute_dft(plan, fdata, fdata)
         t4 = MPI_wtime()
!
! print solutinos
         tplan = t2 - t1
         tmid = t3 - t2
         texec = t4 - t3
         write(*,*) 'in module: ', myid, 'of ', nproc
         if (myid.eq.0) print*,'Tplan=',tplan,'   Tmid=',tmid,'   Texec=',texec
!
! deallocate and destroy plans
   call fftw_destroy_plan(plan)
   call fftw_mpi_cleanup()
   call fftw_free(cdata)
   call mpi_finalize(ierr)
!
end subroutine
!
! ***** Subroutines ****************************************************
!
 subroutine initial(i, j, L, M, fout)
 use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

 implicit none

 integer(C_INTPTR_T), intent(in) :: i, j, L, M
 complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), intent(out) :: fout
 real(C_DOUBLE), parameter :: amp = 0.25
 real(C_DOUBLE) :: xx, yy, LL, MM, r1

   xx = real(i, C_DOUBLE) - real((L+1)/2, C_DOUBLE)
   yy = real(j, C_DOUBLE) - real((M+1)/2, C_DOUBLE)
   LL = real(L, C_DOUBLE)
   MM = real(M, C_DOUBLE)

   r1 = sqrt(((xx/LL)**2.) + ((yy/MM)**2.))
   if (r1 .le. amp) then
     fout = CMPLX(1., 0. , C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX)
         else
           fout = CMPLX(0., 1. , C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX)
         endif

     return
  end Subroutine
! **********************************************************************
end module


!to compile seperately
!mpif90 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -c myfft.f90 -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm
!mpif90 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -c main.f90 -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm
!mpif90 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib myfft.o main.o -lfftw3_mpi -lfftw3 -lm
!to execute
!mpirun -n #nprocs ./main
```

```
program main
  use myfft
  implicit none

  call myfft_setup
  write(*,*) 'Hello World from process: ', myid, 'of ', nproc

  stop
end
```

Comment: Could you post exactly the program you are using, please? The above will not compile as you have not declared cdata or plan (and possibly others)

Comment: I have edited the code, actually the undefined variable can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but I can't reproduce your error with the simplified main, from main I get the expected output. I am using gfortran 7.4 and openmpi version 2.1.1, what are you using? I very much doubt fftw3 has anything to do with the above, what happens if you delete all reference to fftw3? What happens if you recompile everything from scratch? To me it looks more like a compilation problem than anything else.

Comment: I have posted the exactly program. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: my gcc version is 10.2.0 . The compilation seems OK on my PC.

Comment: I will try to recompile, thanks for the advice. Appreciate it.

Comment: This is not how MPI works (best). `MPI_Init()` at the beginning of your program, and `if (0 == rank) ...` "protect" the serial code.